# How to display an image with php?

Tags: php

I have this code, but the image doesn't show. Appears like broken link. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried different ways to display the image, but I can't display it. 
The image is from the database, and I need to display into a row to belong a slider.

```
<?php 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM alianzaclientes WHERE tipoClienteAlianza = 3 ";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$res) die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
     list($id, $nombre, $url, $resena, $imagen, $tipoClienteAlianza) = mysql_fetch_row($res);  

     $id = $row['id'];
     $nombre = $row['nombre'];
     $url = $row['url'];
     $resena = $row['resena'];
     $imagen = $row['imagen'];
     $tipoClienteAlianza = $row['tipoClienteAlianza'];
?> 

<?php 
echo $imagen  
?>
```

Comment: What value is holding $row['imagen'] ?

Comment: Please post the result of `echo $imagen`

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
<img src="<?=$url?>">
```

If $imagen variable contains URL then pass it as in src in img container. If it's just file name then make URL with that file name..

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `img src='base_url().$imagen'` for this.

where `base_url()` is the path of the your directory where image was uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

If `$imagen` is holding a local image you can do something like this:

```
<img src='path/to/image/<?php echo $imagen;?>'
```

if `$imagen` is holding an image on the internet, you can do something like:

```
<img src='<?php echo $imagen;?>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant save an image in the database, this will be the file name and you need to upload the image on the server.. To echo an image you need to know the path where you have uploaded it..

 So if `$imagen = 'image.jpg'`. 
You need to echo this:

```
echo '<img src="path/ofimage/'.$imagen.'" />';
```

Outputs:

```
<img src="path/ofimage/image.jpg" />
```